# PowerShell - Excel filtering condition and assigning one column to multiple columns

Tags: excel, powershell, filtering, comobject

Is it possible to achieve my desired Output using the Excel-COM Object?

I have most of it down but there are two things that I haven't been able to achieve, hoping someone can help.

1. Filter the Yes and No Column and show Only the rows that has ー 〇
2. After filtering, Assign the Title to its corresponding Description

I was able to Filter the Yes and No column. However, I can't assign the Title to its correct Description (because of the Blank Cells).

**This is the Input:**
[image]

**This is my Desired Output:**
[image]

**This is my Current Output:**
[image]

And also, can I achieve this by using a HashTable?